# Why isn't my Angular "Tour of Heroes tutorial" not rendering anything on <app-root>?

Tags: angular, typescript

[github repo](https://github.com/michaelagard/Angular-Bears)

For whatever reason, my Angular app isn't rendering at all when I visit my dev server: http://localhost:4200/

The only difference between the tutorial and my code is the theme.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular: Bears From Around The Multiverse</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

I must be missing something minute, because I've read over the code reviews four times now and can't seem to spot the differences yet.

Running the unit tests that are built in, I see that this error occurs.

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
```

A couple of more errors occurs that might be unrelated based off the error message:

```
DashboardComponent should create
Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("<h3>Top Bears</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let bear of bears" class="col-1-4" [ERROR ->]routerLink="/detail/{{bear.id}}">
    <div class="module bear">
      <h4>{{bear.name}}</h4>
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DashboardComponent.html@2:48
```

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token ':' at column 5 in [/detail/{{bear:id}}] in ng:///DynamicTestModule/BearsComponent.html@4:7 ("
<ul class="bears">
  <li *ngFor="let bear of bears">
    <a [ERROR ->]routerLink="/detail/{{bear:id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{bear.id}}</span> {{bear.name}}
    </a>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/BearsComponent.html@4:7
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
<ul class="bears">
  <li *ngFor="let bear of bears">
    <a [ERROR ->]routerLink="/detail/{{bear:id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{bear.id}}</span> {{bear.name}}
    </a>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/BearsComponent.html@4:7
Parser Error: Unexpected token ':' at column 5 in [/detail/{{bear:id}}] in ng:///DynamicTestModule/BearsComponent.html@4:7 (" <li *ngFor="let bear of bears">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{bear:id}}">
      <span class="badge">[ERROR ->]{{bear.id}}</span> {{bear.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/BearsComponent.html@5:26
Parser Error: Unexpected token ':' at column 5 in [/detail/{{bear:id}}] in ng:///DynamicTestModule/BearsComponent.html@4:7 ("ear of bears">
    <a routerLink="/detail/{{bear:id}}">
      <span class="badge">{{bear.id}}</span>[ERROR ->] {{bear.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/BearsComponent.html@5:44
```

The expected outcome of all this should look close to the tutorial provided here: https://angular.io/tutorial

Currently all I see is the page I mentioned above.

EDIT: It was pointed out below that I should probably think to look in the dev console. Which led me to see a typo in referencing bear.id in https://github.com/michaelagard/Angular-Bears/blob/master/src/app/bears/bears.component.html

Changing bear:id to bear.id allowed the app to fully render. Always check that console.

Comment: Welcome to Angular and thank you for taking the time to complete the tutorial. You can download the source code for the tutorial and compare the difference. The link is at the end of the first section.

Comment: I think you forgot to import `RouterModule` in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: I'll keep looking over the source code, but currently I'm not able to spot the difference.

Comment: @Korfoo Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe I've done this here: https://github.com/michaelagard/Angular-Bears/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @kaiguy in the `imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
]` you should try adding `RouterModule`

Comment: I just did this. https://github.com/michaelagard/Angular-Bears/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts . I re-ran the unit test, and it still says "'router-outlet' is not a known element:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run unit tests you should keep in mind that angular uses a single module for every unit test. That means considering your app.component.spec:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

You have one module which just has AppComponent as declarations, but knows nothing about a router etc. It should look like this:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

That is why your unit tests fails with `routerLink is not a known element`, but that shouldn' affect your app when running on localhost.

EDIT:

I took a look at your repo, in app.module you don't have to import RouterModule because it is already imported via app-routing.module. Also Try to add `CommonModule` to your imports, I know it is also not in the angular tutorial but you need that module to use built in directives and pipes like *ngFor etc.

Have you viewed the debug console in chrome? There might be the error you looking for (hit ctrl+shift+c) and switch to console at the top.

Comment: Coming from React, I didn't even think of looking at the console. I've only been digging into development for like 6 months, but I really should have thought to look there. There was a typo in BearsComponent {{bear:id}} should have been {{bear.id}}. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Import **RouterModule** into your **app.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Add RouterModule into your imports []

**like this:**

```
 imports: [RouterModule]
```

Comment: I just did this. https://github.com/michaelagard/Angular-Bears/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts . I re-ran the unit test, and it still says "'router-outlet' is not a known element:"

Comment: can you share your routing.module.ts file?

Comment: I don't have a routing.module.ts file, but I do have a app-routing.module.ts which I think is the same thing. https://github.com/michaelagard/Angular-Bears/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Then share the same file  app-routing.module.ts and app.module.ts

Comment: have you added AppRoutingModule in your AppModule?

Comment: Yes AppModule https://github.com/michaelagard/Angular-Bears/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts and AppRoutingModule https://github.com/michaelagard/Angular-Bears/blob/master/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a simple replacement:

In your `bears.component.html` I've simply replaced router link with:

`<a [routerLink]="['/bear', bear.id]">`, and it works

Comment: That's exciting!, but it breaks my bear list component. None of the links on the list work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure if your **app.component.html** has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice, but I have <router-outlet> in my app.component.html.